# Generator of contraction semigroup

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Assume $A$ is a symmetric operator in a Hilbert space, which generates a contraction semigroup (a priori it is not known, whether this semigroup is self-adjoint). Is A then self-adjoint?

Comment: Yes. The spectrum of a symmetric densely defined operator is either the entire plane or the upper or the lower half plane or a subset of the real line; in the latter case the operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thanks! (I assume in the real case one can complexify and conclude likewise, right?)

Comment: Indeed, complexification should work in the real case